# getting issue in kibana dashboard - set fielddata=true

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5, metricbeat

I am getting docker performance data using metricbeat and I am trying to produce Dashboards out of Docker Performance Data.

Errors I am getting In Kibana Dashboard: 
[image]

And I enabled fielddata:true in metricbeat.template.json : 
[image]

and then I restarted Metricbeat and Kibana and started. 
Issue still remains. These are the three errors :

```
Visualize: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [docker.container.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.

Visualize: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [docker.container.id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.

Visualize: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [docker.container.image] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.
```

Can anyone help to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the version of ES you're using ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the `mappings` for the fields (`name,id,image`), by enabling the **fielddata** to **true**. Your mapping could look something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "image": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields) as well. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I guess the issue is with using the type **text** for aggregating, which is ideally leading towards to the above exception. Text type field is `analyzed` by nature, which could be normally utilized for *full-text* searches. What if you consider using an **unanalyzed** `keyword` for *aggregation* purposes, which might do the trick for you. You could also read up more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default) and have a look up at this [ticket](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/issues/643) which literally talks about the same controversy.

Comment: this is the mapping I tried ( in the answer section mentioned below ) - i am getting a different error called "Courier Fetch"

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan If my answer had helped you, vote it up or if it actually answered feel free to mark it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the mapping I have tried:

```
PUT /metricbeat-*/_mapping/docker
{
  "properties":{
    "container":{
      "type":"text",
      "fields":{
        "name":{
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "id":{
          "type":"keyword"
        },
        "image":{
          "type": "text",
                    "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping works. 
But, I am getting a different error now - Courier Fetch: 30 of 40 shards failed

Comment: Well this is totally another issue from the previous. You might have to take a look at several reasons due to why it's occurring. This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053967/courier-fetch-shards-failed) , this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3221) and [this thred](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/courier-fetch-n-of-n-shards-failed/27814) might help you.