# kibana: change the threadpool queue size

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I have the same issue as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053967/courier-fetch-shards-failed). Seems that the changing of the queue size for the search threadpool resolve it:

```
curl -XPUT http://your_es:9200/_cluster/settings
{
    "transient":{
        "threadpool.search.queue_size":10000
    }
}
```

However this API does not work in elasticsearch 5.x

Can't find the new API to use.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting is not configurable through an API anymore.

It's a setting that's per node and not global per cluster, thus can only be configured in the yml configuration file. And it should be `thread_pool.search.queue_size`.

Relevant documentation on this you can find [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_threadpool_settings). Relevant snippet:

> The prefix on all thread pool settings has been changed from threadpool to thread_pool.
>
> ...
>
> Thread pool settings are now node-level settings. As such, it is not possible to update thread pool settings via the cluster settings API.